# Subset rows containing not 0 elements in a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

> ```
>   cln1    cln2    cln3    cln4    
>     0      1        2      0   
>     3      9        7     12
>     1      0       13      0   
>     4     98       23     11
> ```

I would like to subset only that rows and columns not containing 0 elements. The desired output will be:

> ```
>   cln1    cln2    cln3    cln4    
>     3      9        7     12
>     4     98       23     11
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf":

```
> mydf[!rowSums(mydf == 0), ]
  cln1 cln2 cln3 cln4
2    3    9    7   12
4    4   98   23   11
```